# addEventListener of adding 1 on each click

Tags: javascript

I have created 2 buttons and a display windows. I want the display windows can add 1 if I click + button. I want the display windows can subtract 1 if I click - button.
However, the function seems doesnt works. May I know what is the problem of my code:

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('add');
let subtractButton = document.getElementById('subtract');
let humanGuess = document.getElementById('human-guess');

function addNum() {
  humanGuess.value = +humanGuess.value + 1;
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', addNum)

function subtractNum() {
  humanGuess.value = -humanGuess.value - 1;
}

subtractButton.addEventListener('click', subtractNum)
```

```html
<div class="number-controls">
  <input type="number" id="human-guess" min=0 max=9 value=0>
  <button class="number-control left" id="subtract">-</button>
  <button class="number-control right" id="add">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It is because of `-humanGuess.value - 1`. `+` is used to convert it from a `string` to `Number` typt.  Either you should use `+humanGuess.value - 1` or `parseInt(humanGuess.value)  - 1` or `Number(humanGuess.value) - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the first minus in `humanGuess.value = -humanGuess.value - 1;` to a plus. [The `+` is used to return the numeric representation of a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) a.k.a Unary plus. The way you have it originally, it's [flipping the number from negative to positive or vice versa, and then subtracting 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_negation) a.k.a Unary negation.

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('add');
let subtractButton = document.getElementById('subtract');
let humanGuess = document.getElementById('human-guess');

function addNum() {
  humanGuess.value = +humanGuess.value + 1;
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', addNum)

function subtractNum() {
  humanGuess.value = +humanGuess.value - 1;
}

subtractButton.addEventListener('click', subtractNum)
```

```html
<div class="number-controls">
  <input type="number" id="human-guess" min=0 max=9 value=0>
  <button class="number-control left" id="subtract">-</button>
  <button class="number-control right" id="add">+</button>
</div>
```